# How to access "hidden" file(s) inside .jpg file?

Tags: encryption, jpeg

I have this .jpg file that cannot be opened nor viewed. But the thing is my friend who sent me this file said that this file actually contains hidden files inside and is MOST likely encrypted. I searched on Google and I found out that I had to rename the extension ".jpg" to ".zip" and tried to extract the file but it doesn't work. I forgot the message that was shown during my attempt to extract. Maybe the file is actually not a .jpg but something else and is corrupt or maybe it has "hidden" files inside.

So I'm wondering if you guys could help me out.

Comment: Open the file in notepad++ and if it's a zip it should look like this : http://prntscr.com/frwe5w `PK` is the zip identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TrIDNet http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html. I didn't test it but I think that you seek for something like this. Your file has an unknown type and you must find with which known type it matches.